# Leading digits of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory

There is a standard problem to show that the distribution of leading digits of $2^n$ is that the digit $k$ occurs with the frequency $\log_{10}(k+1)-\log_{10}(k)$. (This easily generalises to other bases --- though base 2 is rather pointless!)

Since Fibonacci is also ``exponential except for an error term''. Is this true for that as well --- or does the error term make it fail?

Comment: The error term is $o(1)$, so whatever you have for $2^n$ should also work for the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: How could the error term possibly affect the distribution of the _leading_ digit? 

Comment: The phrasing with the emphasize on the error term is perhaps confusing, but then I do not (fully) understand the remark of GH as the 'base' is not 2 for Fibinacci. Okay, in the end 'the reason' is 'the same'; I will expand my answer a bit. 

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is true. The sequence of Fibonacci numbers is known to satisfy Benford's Law. 
See the [wikipedia page of Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) for details (in particular see Distributions that satisfy Benford's law exactly).

More specifically, L. C. Washington showed in [Benford's Law for Fibonacci and Lucas numbers, 
Fib. Quaterly 1981](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/19-2/washington.pdf) that both Fibonacci and Lucas numbers satisfy the extended Benford's Law (that is arbitrary base as mentioned in the question).
The key part of the proof is to show that $n \log \phi$ is uniformly distributed modulo $1$ where $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio (the base of the logarithm being the one for which the law should be established). This is achieved using Weyl's equidistribution theorem.